# How to build redis server and redis cli using docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am new to using `docker-compose`. I am trying to build a redis server and a redis cli. When I do `docker-compose up` on the following, it says `Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused.` What I am doing wrong?

Note: The redis server runs at port 6379 by default.

```
version: '3'

services:

  redis-server2:
    image: "redis:latest"
    command : redis-server

  redis-cli2:
    image: "redis:latest"
    ports:
      - "6379"
    depends_on:
      - redis-server2
    links:
      - redis-server2
    command: redis-cli
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`links` is legacy feature of Docker(refer [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links)).

Instead of `links`, try this.

For this `docker-compose.yml` to work properly, your `redis.conf` must include `bind 0.0.0.0` option. Otherwise, `redis-server` listen on `localhost` only by default so that other hosts including `docker containers` couldn't access the `redis-server`.

```
version: '3'

networks:
    redis-network:
        driver: bridge

services:

  redis-server2:
    image: "redis:latest"
    command : redis-server  

    networks:
        redis-network:
            aliases:
                - redis-server

  redis-cli2:
    image: "redis:latest"

    depends_on:
      - redis-server2

    command: redis-cli -h redis-server

    networks:
        redis-network:
            aliases:
                - redis-cli
```